# How to display a specific shortcut key in HTML?

Tags: html

In HTML you can set your own shortcut keys in a form:

```
<label accesskey="n">name</label>
```

But, how would be the preferred form to display the "n" to make the user notice that this letter is the shortcut? The old convention is to display it **underlined**, which in HTML should be like this:

```
<label accesskey="n"><u>n</u>ame</label>
```

... but since `<u>` tags are discouraged in HTML5, is there a standard (or conventional) form to display this kind of shortcut characters in a HTML page?

P.S.: I know I can set a specific style through something like `<span class="mystyle">n</span>`, but I'm asking for an easier solution - preferrably some specific **HTML tag**.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no underline tag in html5. The u tag was modified to  represent text that should be stylistically different from normal text, such as misspelled words or proper nouns in Chinese

Comment: You could style the attribute `accesskey` instead.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I wish I could, but the `accesskey` characterizes the whole `label`. How to make it style just one of its letters?

Comment: @ThisClark Thanks, but I excluded that approach a priori in my question.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use CSS to append the accesskey using CSS.

```css
[accesskey]::after {
    content: " [" attr(accesskey) "]";
}
```

```html
<label accesskey="n">name</label>
```

The only other option I can see (if you don't want to manually highlight the accesskey itself) is to use JavaScript to wrap the key.

```js
// This uses ES6 syntax
// [].find() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
// NodeList.forEach() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach
// ChildNode.replaceWith() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith

function parseHTML(htmlString) {
    return document.createRange().createContextualFragment(htmlString);
}

function findFirstTextNode(element) {

    return Array.prototype.find.call(element.childNodes, (node) => (
        node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
    ));
    
}

// Extremely basic implementation
function sprintf(string, ...args) {

    return args.reduce(
        (rendered, item) => rendered.replace("%s", item),
        string
    );

}

function highlightAccessKey(
    el,
    replaceString = "<span class=\"accesskey\">%s</span>",
    appendString = "<span class=\"accesskey\">[%s]</span>"
) {

    let accesskey = el.getAttribute("accesskey");
    let textNode = findFirstTextNode(el);

    if (textNode) {

        let text = textNode.textContent;
        let index = text.indexOf(accesskey);

        if (index > -1) {

            text = (
                text.slice(0, index)
                + sprintf(replaceString, accesskey)
                + text.slice(index + accesskey.length)
            );
            
        } else {
            text += sprintf(appendString, accesskey);
        }

        textNode.replaceWith(parseHTML(text));

    } else {
        el.appendChild(parseHTML(sprintf(appendString, accesskey)));
    }
    
}

document
    .querySelectorAll("[accesskey]")
    .forEach((el) => highlightAccessKey(el));
```

```css
.accesskey {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<label accesskey="n">name</label>
```

Sadly, there's not an out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: The CSS-based solution is the most approximate to my expectatives that I've read so far. Thanks!

Comment: Somewhat shorter version from 2022: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/oka5v4w6/

Comment: Can you explain a bit why `parseHTML` is needed? Doesn't the browser parse what JavaScript creates? See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/74808236/6607497 for a more complex challenge.

Comment: @U.Windl it's been a few years since I wrote this code and I haven't looked at it since, but it seems like `parseHTML` is designed to convert a string into DOM elements which can then be added to the page using `appendChild`. I believe that `appendChild` would fail if it were given a string and the newer method, `append`, would treat a string as text

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `title` attribute to display the shortcut when the element is hovered:

```html
<label accesskey="n" title="shortcut-key: n">name</label>
```

Comment: Actually that is useless: The idea of accesskeys is that you use the *keyboard* to navigate. When you have to hover over the element using the mouse, you can also click, no need to go for the keyboard then!

Answer (score 2):

Solution with little js

```js
var sc = document.querySelectorAll('[accesskey]');
for (i = 0; i < sc.length; i++) sc[i].innerHTML = sc[i].innerHTML.replace(sc[i].accessKey, '<a>' + sc[i].accessKey + '</a>');
```

```css
[accesskey]>a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<label accesskey="m">name</label>
```

Comment: Though I'd rather not to use javascript, this approach fixes with my requirements. Thanks!

Comment: I only wonder: How efficient is `document.querySelectorAll('[accesskey]')`? Would it be preferable to call a script with the ID of the element and the accesskey as parameters to add the accesskey and styling to the element? Also what would happen if you select `i` as accesskey in "Mississippi"? Would it only highlight the first occurrence, or all of them?

Comment: @U.Windl `document.querySelectorAll('[accesskey]')` include in all html elements with `accesskey` property. In context of the question this a good practice. Magic in the body of the cycle is up to you. You can use other js methods so that all `i` are marked.

Answer (score 1):

Check it.

```css
label[accesskey]>p::first-letter {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<label accesskey="n"><p>name</p></label>
```

Comment: I thank for the effort, but the shortcut does not fall always in the first position. How would you make it for `<label accesskey="a">name</label>` ? (BTW: I didn't downvote. I sincerely thank you for the answer).

Comment: @LittleSanti you wanted it to be easy. all other underline solutions are more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I put the letter with an Underline to show the shortcut on buttons or labels. There isn't a convention on HTML5 with the way to set it.

Also you can add the title attribute to show a little description with Shortcut Key.

Something like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')" title= "Shortcut: n" accesskey = "n">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, my own answer is to use `<abbr>` or `<mark>` (which are the most semantically approximated tags I've found for my purposes), in this mood:

#### With abbr

```css
abbr {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<p><label accesskey="n"><abbr>n</abbr>ame<input name="a1"/></label></p>
```

#### With mark

```css
label mark {
  background-color: transparent; /* resets the bg color */
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<p><label accesskey="n"><mark>n</mark>ame<input name="a1"/></label></p>
```

Comment: But that is a very *manual* way of highlighting the accesskey.